# Unity) I can't stop the sliding animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

This is my code and I see issues in StartCoroutine() (In line 137) after I press Space and start the sliding animation, the animation doesn't end. It doesn't seem to change the speed when sliding starts too.
I can't find any problems here. Thank you for Helping.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isSliding = false;

    public CapsuleCollider2D regularColl;
    public CapsuleCollider2D slideColl;

    SpriteRenderer rend;
    public float movementSpeed = 3.0f;
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2();
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    [SerializeField] float normalSpeed, runSpeed, crouchSpeed, slideSpeed;

    Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateState();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            prefromSlide();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveCharacter();
        
    }

    private void MoveCharacter()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (movement.x > 0)
        {
            rend.flipX = true;
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0)
        {
            rend.flipX = false;
        }
        
        rigidbody2D.velocity  = movement.normalized * movementSpeed;
        Vector3 moveDir = (Vector3.forward * movement.y) + (Vector3.right * movement.x);
    }

    private void UpdateState()
    {
        //걷기
        if (Mathf.Approximately(movement.x, 0) && Mathf.Approximately(movement.y, 0))
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMove", false);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMove", true);
        }


        //달리기
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            movementSpeed = runSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isRun", true);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            movementSpeed = crouchSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouch", true);
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isRun", false);

            movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouch", false);
        }


        //대기상태 x방향 설정
        if (movement.x > 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 1);
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 0);
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", -1);
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 0);
        }


        //대기상태 y방향 설정
        if (movement.y > 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 1);
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 0);
        }
        else if (movement.y < 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", -1);
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 0);
        }

        animator.SetFloat("horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("vertical", movement.y);

        
    }

    private void prefromSlide(){
        isSliding = true;

        animator.SetBool ("isSlide", true);

        regularColl.enabled = false;
        slideColl.enabled = true;

        if (!rend.flipX) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector2.right * slideSpeed);
        }   else{
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector2.left * slideSpeed);
        }

        StartCoroutine (stopSlide());
    }

    IEnumerator stopSlide(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.8f);
    
        animator.SetBool ("isSlide", false);

        regularColl.enabled = true;
        slideColl.enabled = false;
        isSliding = false;
    }

    
}
```

Before this code I made it a separate script but had a lot of issues and I integrated it to my original playerController script. after that it seemed to work but the sliding animation didn't end. I don't exactly know how IEnumerator works so I couldn't come up with any solutions.

Comment: why not put both into one single routine in the first place?

Comment: Please make sure that you only include the relevant pieces of code. Since line numbers are not displayed here, please point out which part of the code you think may be causing the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use both `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` and `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` in your script.
You can't have those two components on the same object.
My bet is that you only have a Rigidbody2D and that your script stops at `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`.

You must have an error in your console saying `"there is no Rigidbody attached to this gameObject"`.

You have assigned your Rigidbody2D in a field

```
rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

You should use it:

```
  if (!rend.flipX) {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce (Vector2.right * slideSpeed);
        }   else{
            rigidbody2D.AddForce (Vector2.left * slideSpeed);
        }
```

instead of

```
   if (!rend.flipX) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector2.right * slideSpeed);
        }   else{
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector2.left * slideSpeed);
        }
```